# retrieving data from 2 tables using a coulmn which is same in both the table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 tables in the database called details and report both the tables have a common field called ono(order number) i need to retrieve the data from both the tables for a specific order number and display that in a table using php. i am able to display only data from a single table.

code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("name");
$term = $_POST['term'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from details where details.ono='$term'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<table width='1400' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' border='0'>";
echo "<tr><td>Patient Name: ".$row['details.pname']."</td><td>Order NO:         ".$row['report.labid']."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Ph no: ".$row['phno']."</td><td>Age: ".$row['age']."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Ref doc: ".$row['rdoc']."</td><td>Received on: ".$row['Sdate']."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</fieldset>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Could it be because your mysql query is just selecting from details and not from report?

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions instead og mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and will not be supported in the future. Read more here : stackoverflow.com/questions/12097245/php-mysql-v-mysqli-v-pdo‎

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a little bit more what do you want.

You could use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM details INNER JOIN reports ON reports.ono = details.ono AND details.ono='$term'
```

But you could also use UNION ALL it depends on what you want to achieve.

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM details WHERE details.ono='$term'
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2 FROM reports WHERE reports .ono='$term'
```

**NOTE**: don't use mysql_query, use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

**NOTE 2**: try to avoid the use of SELECT *. Specify always the fields you want to use.

Comment: i have the field ono common in both the tables i need to display the details from both the table coresponding to the ono i enter.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in (location and line no)

Answer (score 0):

select * from details d LEFT JOIN `report` r ON r.ono = d.ono where details.ono='$term'

This is a LEFT JOIN, basic SQL you should see the docs or go trough some tutorials

Comment: it says "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given " when the above code is used

Comment: Like someone said in a comment to your question, please use mysqli_ functions, mysql_ is deprecated http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) when combining informations from 2 tables using mysql.

In your case this would look like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from details AS detail LEFT JOIN 
report AS report ON (detail.ono = report.ono) where detail.ono='$term'");
```

Be sure to use sth. like  [mysqli::escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to make sure you are secured against sql injection attacks.

Comment: it says "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given " when the above code is used